# Storing password for Remote Desktop inside Bitlocker bucket and not inside Credential Manager

Tags: windows-10, security, remote-desktop, bitlocker, credentials-manager

I have a Bitlocker bucket on my laptop, and I have saved a .rdp (Remote Desktop) connection shortcut inside.

I enabled the "Saving Credentials" so that clicking the .rdp will immediately access the remote server without asking for credentials.

Company security procedures do not let me store passwords anywhere except for inside this Bitlocker bucket. I realize though that Windows stores the credentials inside the Credential Manager and not inside the .rdp file

Is there any way of forcing Windows to store the password inside the .rdp file, so that it will be kept inside the encrypted bucket? Or any other way of achieving my aim, which is to access RDP without having to enter the password each time, but keeping the password saved inside the bucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Remote Desktop Connection Manager https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44989 will store the (encrypted) password inside of the .rkg configuration file that it uses. And this .rkg file can be stored anywhere, including inside a Bitlocker bucket